# Connecting to SQL Server 2012 Issues

Tags: sql-server

I got the mysql server running, but for some reason I can't sign into SQL server 2012. I have the instance running, but get an error stating that the system cannot find the file specified. See screenshot for reference. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see on the screenshot that MySql is running, not MS SQL.

Comment: **MySQL <> Microsoft SQL Server**. You cannot use SSMS with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try for a server name ".\" instead of "localhost".

Edit: I assume you are using a default instance name, MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: I added another screenshot to show my configuration.

Comment: You cannot use MS Sql Server Management Studio with MySQL. You need something like MySQL Workbench. https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Two things: is it possible that you configured it as a named instance? In which case it could be localhost/MSSQLSERVER

Also, sometimes SQL Browser service needs to be started.